# Coverting JDE Julian Date to Calendar Date within a select statement

Tags: sql, select, julian-date, jde

I have tried so many of the answers from other similar questions and I'm still getting nowhere.

I have a select statement where I am trying to convert a JDE Julian date (6 digit) to a normal calendar date.

The only one I have gotten to return anything is below but the date returned is wrong. *It returned  a date in 2024 when it should have been 2023-06-12 for the julian date 123163*.

`to_date(to_char(1900 + floor(IL.ILTRDJ / 1000)),'YYYY') + mod(IL.ILTRDJ,1000) - 1,`

**I am looking to have something like this:**

`Select  firstname,  lastname, Converted julian date as date position, from ....`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: Date functions are very specific by DBMS. So it looks like your format is YYY (since 1900) and DDD (into the year). Calculate the year however you see fit. You just need to determine how to get the MMDD from the last 3 digits. Again, depends on DBMS.

Comment: I am using Plsql developer against local copies of jde tables.

I think I may have found something that works   
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(IL.ILDGL +1900000),'YYYYDDD')

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method which concatenates the Year with the Remainder Days in YYYYDDD format.

```
select 
  to_date(concat(1900 + floor(123163/1000), mod(123163,1000)),'YYYYDDD') as date_col
from dual;
```

| DATE_COL |
| --- |
| 12-JUN-2023 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mj12onVO)